# stop event execution on datatable pagination click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I have an inline datatable, when I change the data in datatable and click on next page I need to show bootstrap modal. 
if click on **yes** the data should be saved and it should show next page in datatable. When I click on **no** it should stay on the same page
 Now, the problem is without clicking on yes/no buttons in datatable it is going to next page without waiting for user response. It should stay on the same page. I have tried the following to stop the event execution.

```
e.preventDefault()
e.stopPropogation()
e.stopImmediatePropogation()
```

The above events are not working. Your help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `preDraw` event because data can be lost on pagination or on sort also. Also make sure that you are on latest datatable version `1.10.19`.
Doc: https://datatables.net/reference/event/preDraw

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.on( 'preDraw', function (e, settings) {
    if(!confirm('Leave?')) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/6258/

Check all the events available: https://datatables.net/reference/event/

You can also combine [`order`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page) and [`page`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page) event.
Something like:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.on( 'order.dt', myConfirm);
table.on( 'page.dt', myConfirm);

function myConfirm(e, settings) {
    if(!confirm('Leave?')) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code is able to stop the execution, but when we change data in grid I'm appending a class name to particular row. when we click on yes in popup I'm not able to get the edited rows because of preDraw event.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this answer in datatables.net forum.

```
var table=$('#grid').datatable();
table.settings()[0].jqXHR.abort();
```

It will abort the ajax request.